# ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘seqminer’

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm having a problem installing 'seqminer'
Please, help me if anyone recognize this problem or been through this.

- gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
- R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14) -- "Very, Very Secure Dishes"

```
R_CPP_interface.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* getListElement(SEXP, const char*)’:
R_CPP_interface.cpp:37:8: error: ‘strcmp’ is not a member of ‘std’
R_CPP_interface.cpp:37:8: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/string.h:143:12: note:   ‘strcmp’
make: *** [R_CPP_interface.o] error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘seqminer’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/seqminer’
* restoring previous ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/seqminer’
```

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to be related to this issue:

[strcmp et. al. not a member of std?](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=449855)

Based on the answer there, possible solutions may include:

- install and use an earlier version of gcc (<= 4.1)
- download the source, edit `R_CPP_interface.cpp` to insert `#include <cstring>`, then install from the local source

I would also file an issue at the [project Github repo](https://github.com/zhanxw/seqminer/issues).